When I install python modules vscode debugger doesn't see them and I can't use it
So when I installed a module through the vscode terminal it says that it is already installed but the debuggr doesn't see it
I already tried changing the interpreter and using py -m pip install pyautogui but they did not work and I don't know what to try next so please help me

Does this answer your question? Why do I get a "ModuleNotFoundError" in VS Code despite the fact that I already installed the module? Look at Brett Cannon's answer first; he's one of the devs.

If none of the answers there are helpful, please add details: 1) What command did you run to install it? 2) What does your code look like? You might be able to reproduce the issue with as little as the import statement; see [mre]. 3) What do you mean by "did not work"? What was the outcome exactly? 4) Have you checked your interpreter details? e.g. that the interpreter VSCode is using is the same as py is using?

... 5) What do you mean by "debugger doesn't see it"? Probably a ModuleNotFoundError, right? Please provide it.

By default, the debugger uses the same interpreter selected for your workspace. If it doesn't work, you could set python in your launch.json. Read document for more details.

By default, the debugger uses the same interpreter selected for your workspace. If it doesn't work, you could set python in your launch.json, such as "python":"path/to/python".
You could read document for more details.
